# Using Webflow for freelance web development

Tags: wordpress, nuxt.js, next.js, webflow

I have just started out doing web development projects for clients and I have done two so far using NextJS, NuxtJS along with headless WordPress for the CMS. As I also have a full time job these projects take a fair amount of time and I end up working constantly.

I have recently come across Webflow and have messed around with it to see how it works. It seems like if I used Webflow and the CMS is provides I could get through projects much quicker than I would currently.

Do you think that for freelancing using a tool like Webflow is a better idea than what I am currently doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently use Webflow for client projects and I use Next.js at work. I would highly recommend using Webflow for the following reasons on most web dev client projects.

- Speed of customization (You can create components in Webflow and copy and past them into new projects, which allows you to reuse standard parts in seconds)
- CMS already integrated.
- Ability to easily give clients access to edit their own content if they need
- Easily edit SEO settings
- Easily connect other tools like Zapier and Memberstack if you need

Comment: Cheers, I think I'm going to give it a go and see how much time and effort it saves me.